# kivy обновление списка

Tags: python, kivy

помогите мне обновлять список в приложение при нажатии кнопки.Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
#from kivy.uix.image import Image

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

from kivymd.uix.card import MDCardSwipe
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDInputDialog, MDDialog

text_scrolls = ["привет, и чё ?","псс, лайк поставь!"]

KV = '''

<SwipeToDeleteItem>:
    anchor: "right"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: content.height
    type_swipe: "auto"
    on_swipe_complete: app.on_swipe_complete(root)

    MDCardSwipeLayerBox:

    MDCardSwipeFrontBox:

        OneLineListItem:
            id: content
            text: root.text
            _no_ripple_effect: True


<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "screen 1"

                Screen:
                    ScrollView:
                        MDList:
                            id: scroll
                    MDFloatingActionButton:
                        icon: "android"
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        user_font_size: "64sp"
                        on_press:
                            app.show_MDDialog()

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''

class SwipeToDeleteItem(MDCardSwipe):
    text = StringProperty()

class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def build(self):
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        instance_content = self.root.ids.content

        for text_scroll in text_scrolls:
            self.screen.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                SwipeToDeleteItem(text=text_scroll)
            )
        print(text_scrolls)

    def show_MDDialog(self):
        text_scrolls.append(333)
        print(text_scrolls)
        
    
class ContentNavigationDrawer(ScrollView):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что вам нужно иметь возможность редактировать два поля, а затем, когда вы нажимаете кнопку, вы должны иметь возможность редактировать каждое поле (текстовые поля) и после нажатия кнопки вы хотите распечатать что вы вводите в поля, хорошо, для этого сначала удалите строку:

**from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDInputDialog, MDDialog**

Потому что это вызовет ошибку.
Я изменил это на:
**from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog**

Теперь я понимаю, что вы делаете, как поете на экране,
хорошо сделайте следующее:

```
    from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCardSwipe
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
notification=1 #1 is yes, 0 is NO
text_scrolls = ["привет, и чё ?","псс, лайк поставь!","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761","https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761"]
text_scrolls1 = ["привет, и чё ?","псс, лайк поставь!"]
KV = '''
<SwipeToDeleteItem>:
    anchor: "right"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: content.height
    type_swipe: "auto"
    on_swipe_complete: app.on_swipe_complete(root)
    MDCardSwipeLayerBox:
    MDCardSwipeFrontBox:
        OneLineListItem:
            id: content
            text: root.text
            _no_ripple_effect: True
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: "screen 1"
                Screen:
                    ScrollView:
                        MDList:
                            id: scroll
                    MDFloatingActionButton:
                        icon: "android"
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .1}
                        #user_font_size: "64sp"
                        on_press:
                            app.show_MDDialog()
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''
class SwipeToDeleteItem(MDCardSwipe):
    text = StringProperty()
class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.a = 1
        
    def build(self):
        global app
        app=MDApp.get_running_app()
        return self.screen
    def on_start(self):
        instance_content = self.root.ids.content
        for text_scroll in text_scrolls:
            self.screen.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                SwipeToDeleteItem(text=text_scroll)
            )
        print(text_scrolls)
    def show_MDDialog(self):
        text_scrolls1.append(333)
        if notification==1:
            app.notti(title="Result:",text=str(text_scrolls1))
        self.a=self.a+1
        self.screen.ids.scroll.add_widget(SwipeToDeleteItem(text=str(self.a)+str(" https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761")))
      
    def notti(self,title="",text=""):
        self.dialog=MDDialog(
            title=title,
            text=text,
            radius=[21,21,21,21],
            )
        self.dialog.open()
        
    
class ContentNavigationDrawer(ScrollView):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()
TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

Используя этот код, вы можете добавлять еще один элемент каждый раз, когда нажимаете его,
Кстати, если вы хотите узнать больше, вы можете отправить мне сообщения в мой мессенджер facebook https://www.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761

или вы можете проверить и подписаться на мой канал на YouTube https://youtu.be/QByzOUVRMyc